# Selecting an element in jQuery by the onclick attribute

Tags: jquery, onclick, selector

I'm having this markup:

```
<a href='#' onclick='loadpage(121);'>
<a href='#' onclick='loadpage(122);'>
<a href='#' onclick='loadpage(123);'>
```

My question: how can I select the 2nd link object by jQuery using the id 122? I've tried something like `$("a[onclick=loadpage(122)]")` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 12):

All these ways works. Use the one whichever fits your need.

```
$('a[onclick="loadpage(122);"]')​ // match entire onclick value
$('a[onclick^="loadpage(122)"]')​ // match from the left of onclick value
$('a[onclick*="loadpage(122)"]')​ // match anywhere in onclick value
```

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted: it works and adds useful and relevant information.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding in the `;` and placing the `loadpage(122);` in single quotes.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/PQB5U/

```
$("a[onclick='loadpage(122);']")​
```